# Docker: How to start service as root

Tags: linux, docker, centos, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile in which I would like to start `mongo` but also do

```
USER dev
```

Now, when I do

```
FROM docker.io/centos
...
USER dev
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

It doesn't work, because mongo can only be started as `root`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the user to `dev` is you want to run `mongo` as root? Those seem to be conflicting requirements.

You can either set the user back to root

```
USER root
```

or you can use `sudo` to run the program as root.